# Google.com international version?

Tags: google-search, localization

When I visit http://google.com I want to get the international google.com version using the english language and not any kind of a localized version of it.

http://www.google.com/ncr does not work either, because I get: [image: google.com screenshot]

In my [google settings](https://myaccount.google.com/) I have set English as my language.

How do I get the proper international version of google with "Google Search" instead of "Pesquisa do Google"?

Comment: Depending on what browser you use, you'll see different layouts for *Google Search preference*. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b9m2m.png) are [two URLs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7UYVN.png) to check for the right settings. When you visit those URLs, are the settings the same?

Comment: In my country we dont have a custom google page and we get the international version by default, but I tested that with a socks proxy which the server was on hongkong. There should be no difference ,I tried `ncr` it works fine. Also try like this: `https://www.google.com.pr/ncr` I dont know `pr` is correct for portugues or not, you know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using http://www.google.com/search?hl=en

(*Answer's body must be as least 30 characters*)

Comment: I am ready to cry with relief. It works!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Google's NCR (No Country Redirect) parameter is not working anymore as of December 15, 2015 (at least for me)

Luckily, you can still avoid Google's country redirects using the following newer link instead:

http://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=cr

Answer (score 0):

Use this link:
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=FTWzU_K-AoLTOYLJgfAE
All International all the time.
Google.com/ncr does not work anymore for me, browser keeps defaulting to current locale after first use.